# Remove link color and underline from my html signature

Tags: html, css, outlook, signature

Hi I am trying to remove the link(blue) color and the underline from the field "email address" in the email signature. The link color and the underline are not showing when I run the code snippet but they are in the email client. I know this is because of the email client , but is there any way to remove it?

This is the part of the html code that I am referring to.

```
  <tr>
  <td style="font-size: 10pt; color:#6b7f7e; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left:20px; vertical-align: middle; line-height:14px" valign="middle">
   <span style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; color:#6b7f7e;"><img border="0" width="18" alt="Vimeo icon" style="border:0; height:15px; width:15px; vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 2px;"   src="https://naturloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/tel..png"></a>&nbsp; +41 323 440 260</span> <br> <span style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; color:#6b7f7e;"><img border="0" width="18" alt="Vimeo icon" style="border:0; height:15px; width:15px; vertical-align: middle;padding-bottom: 2px;"   src="https://naturloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/wu.png"></a>&nbsp; +1 905 929 2994</span> <br><span style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; color:#6b7f7e; text-decoration:none;"><img border="0" width="18" alt="Vimeo icon" style="border:0; height:15px; width:15px; vertical-align: middle;"   src="https://naturloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/mail.png"></a>&nbsp;  <span style="text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none; color:#6b7f7e">
    daniel@naturloop.com
    </span> <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Bellow is the full HTML. Thanks.

```html
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Email Signature</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</HEAD>
<BODY style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: {{fontFamily}};">

<table style="width: 450px; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; border-right: 1px solid; border-right-color:#6b7f7e; width:180px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">  
 
   <img alt="photograph" width="180" border="0" style="border:0; height:auto; padding-top:10px;  padding-left: 10px; width:180px"  src="https://naturloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/logo.png">
   <span><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/naturloop" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="23" alt="Vimeo icon" style="border:0; padding-left:70px; padding-top:10px; height:23px; width:23px"  src="https://naturloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/linked.png"></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://vimeo.com/naturloop" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="23" alt="twitter icon" style="border:0; padding-right:30px; height:23px; width:23px" src="https://naturloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/vimeo.png">
  </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 10pt; color:#6b7f7e; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top:5px; padding-left: 20px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
        <span><span style="color: #6b7f7e; font-size: 12pt"><strong>DANIEL DINIZO<br></strong></span>
        <span><span style="color: #6b7f7e; font-size: 9pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: #6b7f7e; line-height:px">CEO & Co-founder<br></span>
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 10pt; color:#6b7f7e; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top:5px; padding-left: 20px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
        <span><span style="color: #6b7f7e; font-size: 9pt">Solothurnstrasse 102, CH-2504 Biel<br></span>
       
        <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 10pt; color:#6b7f7e; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left:20px; vertical-align: middle; line-height:14px" valign="middle">
       <span style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; color:#6b7f7e;"><img border="0" width="18" alt="Vimeo icon" style="border:0; height:15px; width:15px; vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 2px;"   src="https://naturloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/tel..png"></a>&nbsp; +41 323 440 260</span> <br> <span style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; color:#6b7f7e;"><img border="0" width="18" alt="Vimeo icon" style="border:0; height:15px; width:15px; vertical-align: middle;padding-bottom: 2px;"   src="https://naturloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/wu.png"></a>&nbsp; +1 905 929 2994</span> <br><span style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; color:#6b7f7e; text-decoration:none;"><img border="0" width="18" alt="Vimeo icon" style="border:0; height:15px; width:15px; vertical-align: middle;"   src="https://naturloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/mail.png"></a>&nbsp; <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #6b7f7e;">daniel@naturloop.com</a>
        </span> <br>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 20px; vertical-align: top; color: #6b7f7e;" valign="top">
        <a href="https://naturloop.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;"><strong style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: #6b7f7e;">www.naturloop.com</strong></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
   
   
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </td></tr>
</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: i dont understand, the current code isnt displaying the stuff you are talking about, can you show a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `text-decoration: none` to `<a>` tag, not `<span>`.

It is because `<a>` tag has `text-decoration: underline` set by default.

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"></a>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the example of the code here ?

Comment: I edited my comment to include a sample code, good luck!

Comment: in which email clients do you want to achieve this? Also, posting code with correct indentation would be helpful!

Comment: outlook and Gmail , I updated my question  with the new html code